Angular AG-Grid writing console "Errors" but not "Exceptions" with Bad data
Seeing following Console errors but NOT Exceptions with AG-Grid's "api.setRowData" Code .
enter image description here
params.api.setRowData in the below screenshot is writing errors reported in the above screenshot. We are fixing the baddata scenario but want to give a clear message to user when Grid is not completely rendering expected data. This I can achieve by catching and handling exceptions or by if Grid supports some State property that confirm "params.api.setRowData" outcome or some faulty/error state. need experts advice on how can present appropriate message to the user when there is such bad data scenario again.
enter image description here
Error is coming from the ag-grid-community.cjs when rendering SVG related data as cell data. This is silently writing errors to Browser Console. Is there is a way to detect or catch these errors so we can handle them and report a meaning error to the user ??
enter image description here
Don't see grid properties or exception handling procedures document for AG-Grid. need experts advice on how to detect bad data scenario or errors with Ag-Grid and present appropriate message to the user.
